# merge two dataframe on two keys in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes. I want to merge them on keys typeA and typeB. I want to merge them on any one of two keys

```
# df_a
  typeA typeB value
0   b    a      3
1   c    d      4


# df_b
  typeA typeB value
0   a   b       1
1   c   d       2
pd.merge(df_a,df_b,on=['typeA','typeB'])
typeA   typeB   value_x value_y
0   c   d        4            2
```

but the result I desired is

```
typeA   typeB   value_x value_y
0 c      d       4            2
1 a      b       3            1
```

As long as the type pair matches,I merge them together.  That means  I want

```
   (df_a['typeA']=df_b['typeA'] And df_a['typeB']=df_b['typeB']) or (df_a['typeA']=df_b['typeB'] And df_a['typeB']=df_b['typeA'])
```

I thought it could be done by switch the column names of df_b and do merge process again. After that combine two merge result together. Just wondering if there is more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: What would the output be if instead of `c`/`d` in `df_a` - you had `a`/`d`?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is `sorted` columns for join before `merge`:

```
df_a[['typeA','typeB']] = df_a[['typeA','typeB']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df_b[['typeA','typeB']] = df_b[['typeA','typeB']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
print (df_a)
  typeA typeB  value
0     a     b      3
1     c     d      4

print (df_b)
  typeA typeB  value
0     a     b      1
1     c     d      2

df1 = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,on=['typeA','typeB'])
print (df1)
  typeA typeB  value_x  value_y
0     a     b        3        1
1     c     d        4        2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!